# DeleteDuplicates in a list of 2-tuples under condition

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

Having a list of 2-tuples, I would like to delete such 2-tuples that have `0` at second position, but only those, whose first element is not unique in the list.
E.g. leave

```
{-2053.5150, -2053.46}, {-802.7016, 0}
```

but delete

```
{-2053.5150, 0}
```

I am using command

```
DeleteDuplicates[list, (Second[#] == 0 & && SameQ[First[#1], First[#2]] &)]
```

but returns the same input. Any suggestions ? Here's a sample list

```
list = {{-2053.5150, 0}, {-2053.5150, -2053.46}, {-2012.7445, 0}, {-1297.0270, 0},
     {-1297.0270, -1297.09}, {-1296.0551, 0}, {-1296.0551, -1296.08}, {-802.7016, 0},
     {-760.9591, 0}, {-757.1460, 0}, {-715.4035, 0}, {-44.5266, 0}, {-44.5266, -44.498},
     {-41.8274, 0}, {-41.8274, -41.456}, {-41.4285, 0}, {-41.4285, -41.456}, {-1.0569, 0},
     {-1.0569, -1.031}, {0.3139, 0}, {0.3139, 0.309}, {0.3140, 0}, {0.3140, 0.309}, {1.0289, 0},
     {1.0289, 1.054}, {1.0290, 0}, {1.0290, 1.054}, {39.7136, 0}, {39.7136, 39.736}, {42.0564, 0},
     {42.0564, 42.055}, {1295.3121, 0}, {1295.3121, 1295.36}, {1296.2841, 0},
     {1296.2841, 1296.3}, {1337.0546, 0}, {2053.4871, 0}, {2053.4871, 2053.48}}
```

Comment: Hi ! Your list is clearly inconsistent. Check it near the end and read in the documentation about proper code formatting guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{-2053.5150, 0}, {-2053.5150, -2053.46}, {-2012.7445, 
   0}, {-1297.0270, 0}, {-1297.0270, -1297.09}, {-1296.0551, 
   0}, {-1296.0551, -1296.08}, {-802.7016, 0}, {-760.9591, 
   0}, {-757.1460, 0}, {-715.4035, 0}, {-44.5266, 
   0}, {-44.5266, -44.498}, {-41.8274, 
   0}, {-41.8274, -41.456}, {-41.4285, 
   0}, {-41.4285, -41.456}, {-1.0569, 0}, {-1.0569, -1.031}, {0.3139, 
   0}, {0.3139, 0.309}, {0.3140, 0}, {0.3140, 0.309}, {1.0289, 
   0}, {1.0289, 1.054}, {1.0290, 0}, {1.0290, 1.054}, {39.7136, 
   0}, {39.7136, 39.736}, {42.0564, 0}, {42.0564, 
   42.055}, {12 {-2053.5150, 0}, 95.3121, 0}, {1295.3121, 
   1295.36}, {1296.2841, 0}, {1296.2841, 1296.3}, {1337.0546, 
   0}, {2053.4871, 0}, {2053.4871, 2053.48}}
```

If order does not matter:

```
Join @@ (If[Length[#] > 1, DeleteCases[#, {_, 0}], #] & /@ 
   GatherBy[list, First])
```

yields:

```
{{-2053.52, -2053.46}, {-2012.74, 
  0}, {-1297.03, -1297.09}, {-1296.06, -1296.08}, {-802.702, 
  0}, {-760.959, 0}, {-757.146, 0}, {-715.404, 
  0}, {-44.5266, -44.498}, {-41.8274, -41.456}, {-41.4285, -41.456}, \
{-1.0569, -1.031}, {0.3139, 0.309}, {0.314, 0.309}, {1.0289, 
  1.054}, {1.029, 1.054}, {39.7136, 39.736}, {42.0564, 
  42.055}, {{-24642.2, 0}, 95.3121, 0}, {1295.31, 1295.36}, {1296.28, 
  1296.3}, {1337.05, 0}, {2053.49, 2053.48}}
```

Comment: For this to work the `list` should start out free of duplicates.  If it is not apply `DeleteDuplicates` before `GatherBy`. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard...you are right, of course, I will amend or delete when time permits, as works for special case, as you refer to and not general case...time poor working 12 hour days at present...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard...I guess also I was not sure, tiredness perhaps, that 'duplicates' were only the ones specified by criteria or same elements Or repeated first element and second element zero...though I agree latter seems more natural...either way very glad your comment explicit

Answer (score 1):

From the [details section of the documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html), it says that

> `DeleteDuplicates[list]` deletes all but the first occurrence of each distinct element that appears in `list`.

So, to make sure that the tuples with 0-s are deleted, we have to sort the list first. Also, 
`Second` is not a built-in function so using `Last` here instead:

```
DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[list, -Abs[#] &], (Last[#2] == 0 && First[#1] == First[#2]) &]
```

You can also use `Part` instead of `Last` - this then works with any $n$-tuple where $n \geq 2$:

```
DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[list, -Abs[#] &], (#2[[2]] == 0 && First[#1] == First[#2]) &]
```

Notice that with two conditions the test has to be of the form `(test1[##] && test2[##])&`.

Comment: That's clear solution, thanks. How it would be in case of 3-tuple and considering second element?

Comment: Edited the answer to fix a bug and to answer your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized function:

```
delDupeOnZeroes[list_, zerpos_, distpos_, any_: False] :=
 Module[{up = Union@Flatten@{distpos}, r = Range@Length@list, zp = zerpos, p, gb, jgb, patt},

  If[any,

   p = Cases[Tally[list[[All, #]]], {val_, num_ /; num > 1} :> val] & /@ up;
   If[Flatten@p === {}, Return[list, Module]];
   patt = MapThread[ReplacePart[ConstantArray[_, Length@list[[1]]],
                        {zp -> 0, #1 -> Alternatives @@ #2}] &, {up, p}];
   DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ patt],

   gb = GatherBy[list, #[[up]] &];
   jgb = Join @@ Pick[gb, Unitize[Subtract[Length /@ gb, 1]], 1];
   DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ (DeleteDuplicates@
                     Pick[jgb, Unitize@jgb[[All, zp]], 0])]]];
```

Use:

Arguments are the target list, position to look for zeroes in sublists, element position(s) to be tested for distinctness, and whether test for distinctness is conjunctive or disjunctive.

Using your example `list`:

```
delDupeOnZeroes[list, 2, 1]

(*
{{-2053.52, -2053.46}, {-2012.74,0}, {-1297.03, -1297.09}, {-1296.06, -1296.08}, 
 {-802.702, 0}, {-760.959, 0}, {-757.146, 0}, {-715.404, 0}, {-44.5266, -44.498}, 
 {-41.8274, -41.456}, {-41.4285, -41.456}, {-1.0569, -1.031}, {0.3139, 0.309}, 
 {0.314, 0.309}, {1.0289,1.054}, {1.029, 1.054}, {39.7136, 39.736}, {42.0564,42.055},
 {1295.31, 1295.36}, {1296.28, 1296.3}, {1337.05, 0}, {2053.49, 2053.48}}

*)
```

Note, this keeps the order of the original list intact, and considers both `0` and `0.` as zeroes (if your list has inexact zeroes where you're looking for them, solutions that do not account for that will fail.)

More complex use cases:

```
list = {{1, 2, 5}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0,1}, {7, 0, 5}};

(* look for 0 in slot 3, drop if any list matches in first pos.*)
delDupeOnZeroes[list, 3, 1]
(* {{1, 2, 5}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {7, 0, 5}} *)

 (* look for 0 in slot 2, drop if any list matches in first pos.*)
delDupeOnZeroes[list, 2, 1]
(* {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {7, 0, 5}} *)

(* look for 0 in slot 2, drop if any list matches in *both* first and third pos.*)
delDupeOnZeroes[list, 2, {1, 3}]
(* {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {7, 0, 5}} *)

(* look for 0 in slot 3, drop if any list matches in *either* first *or* third pos..*)
delDupeOnZeroes[list, 2, {1, 3}, True]
(* {{1, 2, 5}, {2, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```